# String for Return key or Search Key on iPAD

Tags: nsstring, uisearchbar

I am working on the below delegate for the UISearchBar:

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

I am trying to handle a scenario when somebody presses Return key on keyboard or Search key on iPAD keyboard. To check if the user has pressed entered, I am looking the string inside the 'text' parameter passed to this method.

While I debug I get whitespaces or blank in the debug log area and when I do `[text length]` I get 1.

I tried comparing it with an empty string as well but seems thats not true. What exactly is it?

Comment: Sorry for being so dumb. Its a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

Use this check to get the return key.

```
[text isEqualToString:@"\n"]
```